# If value of cell is positive do equation else do another equation

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to figure out how to pull a number from a cell and check if it's positive or negative and then from there do one of 2 equations to produce a final number. This is my code, but it doesn't work because the equations become strings. Not sure if there is a simple solution or if it requires a script of some sort since Google Sheets doesn't have an EVALUATE function.

`=(CONCATENATE(IF(AC2>=0,"100 / (AC2 + 100) * 100","(AC2*-1)/ ((AC2*-1)+100) * 100)"),"%"))`

Edit:

Final Code:
`=CONCATENATE(IF(AC2>=0,ROUND(100/(AC2+100)*100, 0),ROUND((AC2*-1)/((AC2*-1)+100)*100, 0)),"%")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes around your equations so it looks more like..
`=IF(AC2>=0,100/(AC2+100)*100,(AC2*-1)/((AC2*-1)+100)*100)`

Any reason you are concatenating a `%`? Perhaps you just want to format it as a percentage.

Comment: That works. I tried removing the quotes and it kept giving me an error, I must have had some kind of formatting issue. When I tried to format it as a percentage it went from a 2 digit number to like a 5 digit number. So it was just a simpler solution. Appreciate it.